# Redshift cooldown feature using window functions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like a functionality very similar to a forward fill using Redshift. I know that I can use FIRST_VALUE similar to

`FIRST_VALUE(flag) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS flag_ffill`

but my use case is as follows:

- Once the first TRUE flag is reached we still do nothing
- The value is forward filled for 8 rows from the following row as it is on cooldown
- Any TRUE flags during cooldown are treated as FALSE, and the cooldown period is **not** extended past the 8 days

If, for example, the flag is always set to TRUE, the cooldown flag should be TRUE for 8 rows, FALSE for 1 row, then TRUE for 8 rows, etc.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]